# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1273 Unknown collation

Tags: laravel, migration

I have following problem: If I migrate a database table using the console, I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1273 Unknown collection:
>   'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables
>   where table_schema = testlaravel and table e_name = migrations)

In MySqlConnector.php line 56:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1273 Unknown collation:
>   'utf8mb4_unicode_ci '

Comment: please post your `mysql` array from `database.php` in config directory. and please run `composer dump-autoload` or `composer update`.

Comment: 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci ',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

Comment: Would you provide some additional details about the type of migration and what steps you are following on the command line?

Comment: thanks I already solved the problem. Updated Open Server problem disappeared